# How to find time-varying coefficients for a VAR model by using the Kalman Filter

Tags: dynamic, kalman-filter, estimation, autoregressive-models

I'm trying to write some code in R to reproduce the model i found in this [article](https://www.healthcare.uiowa.edu/labs/hbrl-neurosurgery/pub_pdf/2007_Oya_Biosystems.pdf).

The idea is to model the signal as a VAR model, but fit the coefficients by a Kalman-filter model. This would essentially enable me  to create a robust time-varying VAR(p) model and analyze non-stationary data to a degree.

The model to track the coefficients is:

X(t) = F(t) X(t− 1) +W(t)

Y(t) = H(t) X(t) + E(t),

where H(t) is the Kronecker product between lagged measurements in my time-series **Y** and a unit vector, and **X(t)** fills the role of regression-coefficients. **F(t)** is taken to be an identity matrix, as that should mean we assume coefficients to evolve as a random walk.

In the article, from **W(T)**, the state noise covariance matrix **Q(t)** is chosen at 10^-3 at first and then fitted based on some iteration scheme. From **E(t)** the state noise covariance matrix is **R(t)** substituted by the covariance of the noise term unexplained by the model: **Y(t) - H(t)Xhat(t)**

I have the *a priori* covariance matrix of estimation error (denoted **Σ** in the article) written as *P* (based on other sources) and the *a posteriori* as *Pmin*, since it will be used in the next recursion as *a priori*, if that makes sense.

So far i've written the following, based on the articles Appendix A 1.2

```
Y <-                                  *my timeseries, for test purposes two channels of 3000 points*
F <- diag(8)                          # F is (m^2*p by m^2 *p) where m=2 dimensions and p =2 lags
H <- diag(2) %x% t(vec(Y[,1:2]))      #the Kronecker product of vectorized lags Y-1 and Y-2
Xhatminus <- matrix(1,8,1)            # an arbitrary *a priori* coefficient matrix
Q <- diag(8)%x%(10**-7)               #just a number a really low number diagonal matrix, found it used in some examples
R<- 1                                 #Didnt know what else to put here just yet
Pmin = diag(8)                        #*a priori* error estimate, just some 1-s...
```

Now should start the reccursion. To test i just took the first 3000 points of one trial of my data.

```
   Xhatstorage <- matrix(0,8,3000)

   for(j in 3:3000){
            H <- diag(2) %x% t(vec(Y[,(j-2):(j-1)]))
            K <- (Pmin %*% t(H)) %*% solve((H%*%Pmin%*%t(H) + R)) ##Solve gives inverse matrix ()^-1
            P <- Pmin - K%*% H %*% Pmin
            Xhatplus <- F%*%( Xhatminus + K%*%(Y[,j]-H%*%Xhatminus) )
            Pplus <- (F%*% P %*% F)  + Q
            Xhatminus <- Xhatplus
            Xhatstorage[,j] <- Xhatplus 
            Pmin <- Pplus
    }
```

I extracted *Xhatplus* values into a storage matrix and used them to write this primitive VAR model with them:

```
Yhat<-array(0,3000)
for(t in 3:3000){
Yhat[t]<- t(vec(Y[,(t-2)])) %*% Xhatstorage[c(1,3),t] + t(vec(Y[,(t-1)])) %*% Xhatstorage[c(2,4),t]
}
```

The looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkP15.jpg) .

The blue line is VAR with Kalman filter found coefficients, Black is original data..

I'm having issue understanding how i can better evaluate my coefficients? Why is it so off?

How should i better choose the first *a priori* and *a posteriori* estimates to start the recursion? Currently, adding more lags to the VAR is not the issue i'm sure, it's that i don't know how to choose the initial values for Pmin and Xhatmin. Most places i pieced this together from start from arbitrary 0 assumptions in toy models, but in this case, choosing any of the said matrixes as 0 will just collapse the entire algorithm.

Lastly, is this recursion even a correct implementation of Oya *et al* describe in the article? I know im still missing the R evaluation based on previously unexplained errors (V(t) in Appendix A 1.2), but in general?